# i can't import any packages in vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, package

so i'm trying to import the mysql.connector in vs code. as normal i open up the terminal `pip install mysql-connector-python`, all correct in installs succesfully! but when i try to import the package it doesn't.i have a few interpreters that i use
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiV4K.png)

when i choose microsoft store one it's all good i can import i can use the package, but when i choose the other interpreters it just doesn't work i can't import it.the reason i'm not using the microsoft store one it's because it works soooo slow like even a single line of print statement takes about 10 seconds and i'm not sure why does that happens too.What can i do?

Comment: You installed the package for one interpreter, but not for the other, i.e. you have to install the package for each interpreter(s) you want to use it with.

Comment: How can i do that i looked up everywhere i can't find proper information to do that

Answer (score 0):

Usually， this was caused by incorrect python interpreter.

You can use shortcuts **Ctrl+Shift+P** and type `Python: Select Interpreter` to choose the python interpreter which you installed the python package in.